# Excel VBA Loop through some sheets but not all

Tags: excel, vba

I have a workbook with about 12 sheets.  I am trying to apply conditional formatting and data validation to alternating rows from E to Y on sheets 2 through 6.

The validation and formatting are working perfectly, but the sheet loop is giving me a lot of issues.

It keeps applying the loop to Sheet 1, and it doesn't always apply it to each sheet from 2 to 6, although the sheet that doesn't get hit changes.

I'm at a loss.  Some of the code was made with the Record Macro function, so I'm sure it's inefficient and bulky, but here's the code:

```
Sub ListCF()
Dim i           As Integer
Dim j           As Integer
Dim k           As Integer
Dim cl          As Variant
Dim Row         As Variant
Dim ws          As Worksheet

For i = 2 To 6

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(i)

        Worksheets(i).Activate
        Cells.Select
        Selection.FormatConditions.Delete
        Selection.Validation.Delete
        Selection.NumberFormat = "General"

        For j = 5 To 23 Step 2

            Range(Cells(2, j), Cells(50, j)).Select

            With Selection.Validation
                .Delete
                .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
                xlBetween, Formula1:="=Reference!$A$2:$A$50"
                .IgnoreBlank = True
                .InCellDropdown = True
                .InputTitle = ""
                .ErrorTitle = ""
                .InputMessage = ""
                .ErrorMessage = ""
                .ShowInput = True
                .ShowError = True
            End With

        Next j

        For k = 6 To 24 Step 2

            cl = Mid(Cells(2, k).Address, 2, 1)

            Range("$" & cl & 2, "$" & cl & 50).Select

            Selection.NumberFormat = "m/d/yyyy"

            'With Range(Cells(2, k), Cells(50, k))

                Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:= _
                    "=$" & cl & 2 & ">(TODAY()-60)"

                Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority

                With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Font
                    .Bold = True
                    .Italic = False
                    .Color = -16776961
                    .TintAndShade = 0
                End With

                Selection.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False

                Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:= _
                    "=$" & cl & 2 & "<(TODAY()-60)"

                Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority

                With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Font
                    .Bold = False
                    .Italic = False
                    .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorLight1
                    .TintAndShade = 0
                End With

                Selection.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False

            'End With

            Range(Cells(2, k), Cells(50, k)).Select
            Selection.NumberFormat = "m/d/yyyy"

        Next k

    End With

Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: you have too many `Select` and `Selection`

Comment: `With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(i)` - you're not using this at all in the loop

Comment: `Worksheets(i)` refers to the `i`th worksheet counting from left to right in tab order.  Is that the order you are expecting?  Or are you trying to access the sheets with names "Sheet2", "Sheet3", "Sheet4", "Sheet5" and "Sheet6"?

Comment: I was trying to basically loop through Sheets(2), Sheets(3), etc.  Mr. Rado solved my issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is untested, but if I didn't loose any `.` to fully qualify all of the objects under `ws` (worksheet object), it should be OK.

You can loop through all worksheets with `For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets`, and then check is the worksheet index is between 2 to 6 with `Select Case ws.Index`.

**Code**

```
Sub ListCF()

Dim i           As Integer
Dim j           As Integer
Dim k           As Integer
Dim cl          As Variant
Dim Row         As Variant
Dim ws          As Worksheet

For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    Select Case ws.Index
    Case 2 To 6 ' if Worksheet.Index is 2 to 6
        With ws         
            With .Cells
                .FormatConditions.Delete
                .Validation.Delete
                .NumberFormat = "General"
            End With

            For j = 5 To 23 Step 2
                With .Range(.Cells(2, j), .Cells(50, j)).Validation
                    .Delete
                    .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:="=Reference!$A$2:$A$50"
                    .IgnoreBlank = True
                    .InCellDropdown = True
                    .InputTitle = ""
                    .ErrorTitle = ""
                    .InputMessage = ""
                    .ErrorMessage = ""
                    .ShowInput = True
                    .ShowError = True
                End With
            Next j

            For k = 6 To 24 Step 2
                cl = Mid(.Cells(2, k).Address, 2, 1)

                With .Range("$" & cl & 2, "$" & cl & 50)
                    .NumberFormat = "m/d/yyyy"
                    .FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=$" & cl & 2 & ">(TODAY()-60)"

                    .FormatConditions(.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
                    With .FormatConditions(1).Font
                        .Bold = True
                        .Italic = False
                        .Color = -16776961
                        .TintAndShade = 0
                    End With

                    .FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False
                    .FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=$" & cl & 2 & "<(TODAY()-60)"
                    .FormatConditions(.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
                    With .FormatConditions(1).Font
                        .Bold = False
                        .Italic = False
                        .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorLight1
                        .TintAndShade = 0
                    End With
                    .FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False
                End With

                .Range(Cells(2, k), Cells(50, k)).NumberFormat = "m/d/yyyy"
            Next k
        End With
    End Select
Next ws

End Sub
```

Comment: Mr. Rado,

I had to remove this at the end:

    .Range(Cells(2, k), Cells(50, k)).NumberFormat = "m/d/yyyy"

and it works perfectly!  Thank you so much.

Now I just have to study it and figure out where I went wrong.

Comment: @jennar you're welcome, please mark as "answer", by clicking the **V** next to my answer(it should turn green)